# Using "Matrix" to rotate two "Bitmap"

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, android-canvas

I have a `Canvas` and a `Bitmap`.I have to draw bitmap twice on canvas and rotate them.This is my code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ... ;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Camera camera = new Camera();
camera.save();

// First drawing:
camera.rotateX(x_rotate_angle);
camera.rotateY(y_rotate_angle);
camera.getMatrix(matrix);
matrix.postTranslate(0, 0);
matrix.postScale(3, 3);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
camera.restore();

// Second drawing:
camera.rotateX(x_rotate_angle);
camera.rotateY(y_rotate_angle);
camera.getMatrix(matrix);
matrix.postTranslate(10, 10 + bitmap.getHeight());
matrix.postScale(3, 3);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

Result before rotation:

[image]

When bitmaps rotate only **axis X**,all things are fine.In this case result looks like this:

[image]

In both above images you can see that all edges are `parallel`.But when bitmaps rotate **axis Y**,edges will not be parallel(bottom edge of top bitmap crosses top edge of bottom bitmap):

[image]

Did I do any thing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, it's just that you haven't understood the results you were going to get from your code. The camera you're using is a 3D camera and you're seeing the results of moving the camera in 3D space. When you rotate a camera, parallel lines do not in general remain parallel. You noticed the artifact when rotating about the y-axis, but it's also present in your illustration for the x-axis rotation. Notice that for the x-axis, the left and right sides are not parallel; the left side is closer to vertical than the right.

The Android `canvas` object has scale, skew, translate, and rotate operations. If it's 2D operations that you need, you can ditch the `camera` object entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.It seems logical,and I guess it,but it has a challenge: when I draw bitmap with no rotation in (0,0) then translate Camera to (0,0,0),then rotate it and draw bitmap again with new matrix in (0,0),in 3D world we expect that top side of rotating bitmap be covered completely by top side of not rotated bitmap,but result is not.It seems that even you translate camera to (0,y0,0) and rotate axis Y then draw a circle in canvas with origin (x0,y0),circle will be drawn at origin (x1,y1) that y1 <> y0 instead of y1 = y0.

Comment: It seems like you're expecting 3D transforms to behave like 2D ones, which they don't. If that's what you want, ditch the 3D interface you're using and use the one that offers 2D transforms.

Comment: Your reply is true but I do not understand the logic of your latest comment.So I ask another question here.Please look at this question:http://stackoverflow.com/q/13438032/1043882